# The method complexFind(String) is undefined for the type AndroidDriver

Tags: java, appium

When using the method `complexFind` with the Appium Java Lib, I get the error:

> The method `complexFind(String)` is undefined for the type `AppiumDriver`

I have tried using other methods available in the Appium Driver, but I could not use `complexFind`.

Any idea what the problem is? I'm using:

- Appium Version 1.2.0.1
- Java 1.7.0

Comment: please refer to the link below for screenshot of my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ilru3r0qao3jk2/error.png?dl=0

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to do so I can suggest an alternative to `complexFind`

Comment: all i'm trying to do is just tap on a element using the text instead of the  resource id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Complex Find is no longer used in the Appium Java Lib!

It was removed within the last month. Please see [this giant post](https://discuss.appium.io/t/java-client-updates/293) for the full details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you please tell me if there is a way in appium i can find the element using text.

Comment: Yeah you should use uiautomator locator strategy. Ask another question and I'll answer with how to get element by text

Comment: is there any replacement for complex find?